# Was Ravana a vegetarian?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, brahmins

Ravan was half-brahmin and half-demon.His father,the great rishi Vishrava belonged to the Pulastya clan and mother Kaikasi originated from the asura clan.Since he was a brahmin and was the greatest devotee of Mahadev,it might be true that he was a vegetarian.
However it might also be possible that he was a meat eater,due to the fact that he possessed demon genes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ravana was not a vegetarian.

As per **UTTARA KANDA of Valmiki Ramayana**, this is what Ravana did in king Marutta's Maheshvara yajna:

[image: Ravana in king Marut's yajna]

> And then devouring the Maharshis that were present at the place of
>   sacrifice, Ravana, satiated with their blood, again went to the earth. ([English translation source](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-18))

---

The complete story of king Marutta's Maheshvara yajna is given [here](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-18).

Comment: did Ravana observed vegetarianism while he was still learning under the tutelage of his Guru?

Comment: @Elfinforest pls check this http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-10

Comment: As expected lol

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to popular belief, Ravana was not a brAhmana, but a Kshatriya (or at least his son was).

1. [Sri Hanuman attacks demons in Sundara Kanda. After the death of Akshaya, another son of Ravana in the hands of Sri Hanuman, Ravana orders Indrajit to proceed to the battlefield](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sites/valmikiramayan/sundara/sarga48/sundarasans48.%7Ehtm).

> न खल्वियम् मतिः श्रेष्ठा यत्त्वाम् सम्प्रेषयाम्यहम् | इयम् च राजधर्माणाम् क्षत्रियस्य मतिर्मता || ५-४८-१३

> "This thought of my sending you is not indeed the best option. But, this decision is said to be according to the duties of a king and is the commendation of a warrior-class."

Here, Ravana himself declares that he (or his son) was a Kshatriya.

2. [While searching for Sita, Sri Hanuman enters Ravana's palace, where he sees non-vegetarian dishes, which were partly consumed](http://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/sundara/sarga11/sundarasans11.htm).

> मृगाणाम् महिषाणाम् च वराहाणाम् च भागशः || ५-११-११
> तत्र न्यस्तानि मांसानि पान भूमौ ददर्श सः |

> Hanuma saw there in that bar, meat of dear and of buffalo, of wild boar kept separately.

> रौक्मेषु च विशलेषु भाजनेष्व् अर्ध भक्षितान् || ५-११-१२
> ददर्श कपि शार्दूल मयूरान् कुक्कुटामः तथा |

> The best among Vanaras saw half eaten peacocks and chicken in wide vessels of golden colour.

Comment: meat of deer.. spelling

Answer (score 5):

Ravana was **not a vegetarian** according to his own words to Sita

> Ravana listening to Seetha's words which were harsh thereafter replied
> to Seetha unpleasant words which are seen to be pleasant. "In whatever
> way gentle language is used to women in that way they will be under
> control. In whatever way men speak dear words, in that way they will
> be rejected ......................................................................................................................................................
> .......................................................................................................................................................
>
> Above two months you not desiring me as husband **will be killed in my
> kitchen for my breakfast**".
>
> [[1-9, Chapter 22, Book V : Sundara Kanda - Book Of Beauty]](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga22/sundara_22_frame.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a solid maybe.

---

While Ravana definitely ate meat (see the other answers), it can easily be argued that it was lab-meat and thus did not involve killing an animal (because lab meat is single souled). [First of all the population of Lanka is 100 billion and they all eat meat](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424647.html), which makes animal raising kind of impractical.

> “**Ten thousand kotis of titans**, able to change their form at will, feeding on flesh and blood, inhabit Lanka. At their head, their sovereign the wicked Ravana made war on the supporters of the earth as also the Gods who were all overcome by him.”
>
> Having **listened to Bibishana** and weighed his words carefully, Rama expressed himself thus:—

A more direct implication involves an encounter with a [Yaksha in the Mahabharata](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7595.html). Lanka used to be ruled by Yakshas, so it has technology at least as good as them.

The Yaksha is 30m tall, taller than a blue whale is long, yet manages to live on tiny fish. Now, while blue whales also sustain themselves on tiny aquatic animals, the Yaksha can fly, is even more intelligent than a human, and is in the middle of a forest. Thus, it probably implies he doesn't slaughter animals in order to get enough food.

> **Vaisampayana continued**, 'Hearing these accursed words couched in harsh syllabus,[2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7595.html) Yudhishthira, O king, approaching the Yaksha who had spoken then, stood there. And that bull among the Bharatas then beheld that Yaksha of unusual eyes and **huge body tall like a palmyra-palm** and looking like fire or the Sun, and irresistible and gigantic like a mountain, staying on a tree, and uttering a loud roar deep as that of the clouds.

> And having concluded this for certain, he began to perform his ablutions in that lake. And while he descended into it, he heard these words from the sky, **uttered by the Yaksha**,—
>
> '**I am a crane, living on tiny fish**. It is by me that your younger brothers have been brought under the sway of the lord of departed spirits. If, you, O prince, answer not the questions put by me, even you shalt number the fifth corpse. Do not, O child, act rashly! This lake has already been in my possession. Having answered my questions first, do you, O Kunti’s son, drink and carry away (as much as you requirest)!'

---

In case you are wondering how Hanuman can tell what meat is what, they probably have signs so people know what they are eating.

---

Also, I have to wonder, how tall and strong is the tree to support the Yaksha?

---

Lab meat is technically vegetarian by the usual definition as it does not involve killing an animal.