# Can you reverse a diksha?

Tags: shiva, tantra, non-vegetarian, initiation

I took a shiva diksha today at my local temple. I have been a non-vegetarian all of my life. Today the priest at the local temple who initiated me told me that I had to give up eating meat. I agreed and then he gave me a basic shiva diksha and mantra to chant. I now find it difficult to give up eating meat, like chicken and goat. If I eat non-veg after taking this diksha, will I be punished by the gods? I am a very religious person, but I am bengali so my cultural food is very non-veg. Is there any way I can reverse the diksha and go back to the way I originally was without any negative consequences? I want to be a tantrik and follow kashmiri shaivism, but I want to be non-veg. Is this possible? Ravan was a shiva devotee but he ate meat. Why can't I worship shiva and eat meat at the same time? Please help. I would appreciate it if a qualified religious priest pandit expert answered it.

Comment: You changed your decision too quickly - since you got initiated today itself.In this case , you should consult the priest who initiated you,  before asking this question to another qualified religious priest pandit expert here. He will guide you more accurately.

Comment: Kashmir shaivism even harder to find good guru

Comment: 'I would appreciate if a qualified religious priest pandit expert answered it' - see this note to the right on this site's home page: "Like any library, Hinduism Stack Exchange shares great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from any Acharya, Pundit, astrologer, Guru or other trustworthy Counselor."

Comment: I know the answer how you can reverse the Diksha and I even posted a short answer. But after that I realize that I forgot wherein I read about it Lol .. still could not find it. I need to do a more thorough search. You can reverse a Diksha when you realize that you have received a pratikula mantra (unfavorable mantra).

Comment: "Why can't I worship shiva and eat meat at the same time" ofcourse you can!

Comment: The answer given by prakash is correct. You can accept it if it's useful Raj Scindia.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a qualified priest but, I know this would help you.

You can reverse or, in other words, stop deeksha by two ways as mentioned in the Meru Tantra.

1.By telling the mantra to a cow.

2. By writing the the mantra on a [bhurja-patra](https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=bhUrjapattra&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) or a manu script and leaving it in a river which flows all over the year.

But be sure to leave the mantra deeksha, which cant be obtained easily. I was waiting for the guru from several years and cant find one. You are lucky to have a guru.

Don't forget to consult the guru before leaving mantra.Only after his permission you can leave the mantra.It is said that  other wise you will face the negativity (my point is not to make you you afraid but telling the things which i was been told).

Source - I have a heard a Pravachana of a Guru where he told about the methods I gave here.

Comment: I knew about the 2nd method you gave but not about the 1st. BTW do you have Meru Tantram or are these verses quoted in some other book?

Comment: i've not read it any where but ,i've  listend to a guru when telling the pravachana

Comment: Okay thanks and welcome to the site.

Comment: "Ravana never ever consumed meat as he was a bramhin(as far as i know).please tell me if you evr came across the line in Ramayana that ravan coonsumed meat" -- pls see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23787/12304 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/25014/12304

Comment: Can you please provide the references from where you provided this information?

Comment: thanks for providing the lines that mentioned the ravana as a non-vegan.i haven't come across these line so.i have told so.thank for clarifying me and i have learnt a new thing today

Comment: @prakash Your answer has provided useful info. I have edited it slightly. Please keep participating.

Comment: @Rickross thanks alot